# After opening ports 8072 and 8073, not albe to connect to Google cloud VM

Tags: tcp, google-compute-engine

I've Virtual Machine running in Google Compute. I've Ubuntu 14.04 on that VM.

I'm building a AOSP custom ROM on this VM. I needed to open port 8072 and 8073 for new toolchain (for Marshmallow) to start the server. So I followed following steps:
1. ufw was inactive; so I enabled it
2. sudo allow tcp:8072
3. sudo allow tcp:8073
4. sudo ufw status verbose

It showed these 2 ports there.

After some time I restarted the VM; and now I'm not able to connect to it.

I connect using the option "Open in browser window". I also tried with "Open in browser window with custom port" with port 22. But it is not allowing me to connect to it.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a firewall rule set on your instance's network? Every instance usually have a network profile and inside of the network there are firewal rules set. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en

Comment: I have not set any rules except allowing the 2 ports mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you allowed the ufw it blocked new ssh connections, you need to start another instance with the disk from the old instance and to to the /mnt/etc/ufw.conf and set ENABLE=no.

```
# Set to yes to start on boot. If setting this remotely, be sure to add a rule
# to allow your remote connection before starting ufw. Eg: 'ufw allow 22/tcp'
```

`ENABLED=yes`

After that you restart the instance with the old disk the first rule you need to add is **ufw allow 22/tcp**.

But you need to allow the ports 8072 and 8073 on google cloud firewall to allow the connection to the instance.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But when I go to Disks and try to select "New Instance", I can not do that. That option is grayed out. I tried this when the instance was running as well as when it was stopped. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another instance because the disk is in use by an instance.

If you have important information on the disk perform a snapshot before you proceed

1 - Edit instance and make sure "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted" is not checked.

2 - Delete the instance. (Now you have a disk not used by any instance)

3 - Add the olddisk to another instance (Not as root disk)

4 - Edit another instance you have running, and add the old disk to it.

5 - Mount de old disk. (mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt)

6 - edit /etc/ufw/ufw.conf

7 - unmount the disk (umount /mnt)

8 - Edit the instance you mounted the disk and remove the disk from the instance.

9 - Go back to disk tab click on the old disk and create an instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help @No Name. I tried to follow your steps but I can not uncheck the check box "Delete boot disk when deleting instance". I tried to uncheck that when the instance was switched off and also when it was on. In both the cases I was not able to do that. (I created a snapshot.)

Comment: To uncheck the check box you need to Edit the instance.